# Python & MongoDB - How to find by BinData type

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I am new to MongoDB. Anyway, I am trying to save some data that is encrypted and base64 encoded.

```
data = b64encode(self.iv + AES.new(self.key, self.mode, self.iv).encrypt(self.pad2(self.data)))
self.db.users.insert({'data':data})
self.db.users.find({'data':data})
```

The insert works fine, but finding data returns 0 results. MongoDB shell outputs this:

```
db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50f848dc34257b0d5e3d9b29"), "data" : BinData(0,"R1VhaHl3MGpLSStkY0lWU255ZjhneGp2RWk3cEk3MnFRTCsxOTcyOC82WT0=")}
```

How can I find my document by BinData filetype now? I've tried bson.binary.Binary no luck there.

Comment: Are you sure it's returning 0 results? The `find()` method in pymongo returns a cursor.  Perhaps you should try `find_one()` or `find().count()` to gauge success.

Comment: yes it is, as Im doing .count() and its 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you still need this (or why you're converting from binary to base64 to binary), but I hope this helps:

```
import base64
import pymongo
from pymongo import binary
# if pymongo version >= 1.9, use the following instead
# from bson import binary

con = pymongo.Connection()
b64 = base64.b64encode("ajskldfjaklsdjfklasdjf")
bi = binary.Binary(b64)
con.test.test.insert({'foo': bi})
con.test.test.find_one({'foo': bi})
```

Output:

```
{
    u'_id': ObjectId('50f99b4a9f956a1924000000'),
    u'foo': Binary('YWpza2xkZmpha2xzZGpma2xhc2RqZg==', 0)
}
```

Comment: seems like I was attempting to use wrong binary. I tried bson.binary, never realized pymongo has one too.

Comment: ok I tried this myself, and I get error claiming binary does not exist in pymongo. Weird :(

Comment: You may be using a newer version of pymongo.  In the later versions they separated out the binary bits into the `bson` package.  Try `from bson import binary`.  See the following commit https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/commit/9c182809f3e7ce3b93da99a825d0ad73d07689d9